# Elasticsearch и фильтры в интернет-магазины

Tags: elasticsearch, ecommerce

Все атрибуты (свойства) товаров в интернет-магазине хранятся как json в текстовом поле MySQL. Этот же массив свойств вместе с другими параметрами товара индексируются в ElasticSearch.

Нужно реализовать фильтр, как на картинке (вывести все возможные значения и количество найденных товаров по каждому запросу). Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть список параметров, по которым необходимо фильтровать (Диагональ, Цена, Тип матрицы и т.д.) и документы в Elasticsearch, и каким-то образом, нужно получить результат как на картинке.

Самый простой способ - по каждому свойству находить возможные уникальные значения distinct (то есть, для диагонали найти 11", 12.9", 15.9"), а потом для каждого возможно значения посчитать количество найденных товаров (count). Но такой способ - тонна запросов и всё это придётся кешировать.

Есть ли способ получить нужный результат одним запросом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё очень легко решается с помощью агрегаций:

```
GET
{
    "aggs" : {
        "keyname" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "key" }
        }
    }
}
```